# Problem with ifelse() or dplyr::if_else() for dates

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I'd like to convert in vector `mydates` the NA in actual date (`Sys.Date()`) and if the values is a date then do not change anything, but I don't have success using `ifelse` or `if_else` of `dplyr` package. In my example:

```
# Package
library(dplyr)

# My vector
mydates<-c(NA,NA,NA,"2019-03-14","2020-05-01",NA,NA)

# Using ifelse
mydatescorr1<-ifelse(is.na(mydates)==TRUE,Sys.Date(),mydates)
mydatescorr1

[1] "18771"      "18771"      "18771"      "2019-03-14" "2020-05-01" "18771"      "18771" 

#Using if_else
mydatescorr2<-if_else(is.na(mydates)==TRUE,Sys.Date(),mydates)
mydatescorr2 

Erro: `false` must be a `Date` object, not a character vector.
```

Please, any help to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mydates` is a character vector (`class(mydates)`), so when you return `mydates` as it is from the else part you are returning character object and not date. You can use -

```
dplyr::if_else(is.na(mydates), Sys.Date(), as.Date(mydates))
```

Or without `if_else` -

```
mydates <- as.Date(mydates)
mydates[is.na(mydates)] <- Sys.Date()
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```r
tidyr::replace_na(as.Date(mydates), Sys.Date())
```

? (You still have to convert `mydates` to a `Date` type first.) If you wanted you could pipe it:

```r
mydates %>% as.Date() %>% replace_na(Sys.Date())
```